# Adding string to snippets in vs code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I was trying to add a custom snippet but having a problem adding string to the snippet here is the code:

```
"Default cpp formate": {
    "prefix": [
        "include",
        "default"
    ],
    "body": [
        "#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE"
            "   freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);"
            "   freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);"
        "#endif"
            
        "$0",
        ""
    ],
    "description": "This is a c++ snippet",
}
```

In the code the "input.txt" does not come when run the snippet

Comment: You need commas after each of the array lines in the `body`.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Yeah, that was just the first problem while I was fixing the code presentation in the question.  Looks like you have got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

So finally this code worked using escape sequences "/" before every quotes

```
"Default cpp formate": {
    "prefix": [
        "include",
        "default"
    ],
    "body": [
        "#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE",
            "   freopen(\"input.txt\", \"r\", stdin);",
            "   freopen(\"output.txt\", \"w\", stdout);",
        "#endif",
        "$0",
        ""
    ],
    "description": "This is a c++ sniffpet",
},
"for loop": {
    "prefix": "forl",
    "body": [
        "for($1 $2 = $3 ; $2 < $4 ; $2++)",
        "{","   ${0:/* code */}",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "For Loop"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Snippets are a good way to save time while doing cp. To answer your question you can use the snippet below and also there is no need to include custom tab spaces. \t will add tab spaces for you.

```
{
    "cp-extension": {
      "prefix": ["cpp-cp"],
      "body": ["#include <bits/stdc++.h>",
"using namespace std;",
"#define ll long long",
"#define ll long long int",
"#define sz(A) (int)(A).size()",
"#define mp make_pair",
"#define pb push_back",
"#define fr(i,A) for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++)",
"#define mod 1000000007\nvoid solve()",

"{",
    "\t$2",
"}",
"int main() {\n\tios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);cout.tie(NULL);\n#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE",
"\tfreopen(\"input.txt\", \"r\", stdin);",
"\tfreopen(\"output.txt\", \"w\", stdout);",
"#endif\n\n\tll test=1;\n$1cin>>test;\n\twhile(test--)\n\t{\n\t\tsolve();\n\t}\n\treturn 0;\n}\n"
      
      ],
      "description": "Default cpp code for CP"
    }
,
```